# How to Match AND Split REGEX

Tags: java, android, regex, split

How to split by ASCII Character group in REGEX (Android/Java)

**Actual String** 
"আমি আছি i am ইংরেজি থেকে বাংলা"

**Expected Output**  
 
আমি আছি 
i am  
ইংরেজি থেকে বাংলা

Comment: could capture groups help? i don't know

Comment: any patterns to split by ASCII characters

Comment: tried "^\\p{ASCII}*$" but it is not helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always split on the following:

```
(?<=[\u0021-\u007E])\s+(?=[^\u0021-\u007E])|(?<=[^\u0021-\u007E])\s+(?=[\u0021-\u007E])
```

This splits on whitespace preceded by a standard latin character and followed by *not* a standard latin character **or** *not* a standard latin character followed by a standard latin character. Of course you can modify the unicode ranges to accept by looking [here](http://unicode-table.com) as a reference.

Comment: I was going to post `split("(?<=\\P{ASCII})\\s(?=\\p{ASCII})|(?<=\\p{ASCII})\\s(?=\\P{ASCII})")` but you ware first. +1.